# Why we give a method name for GridView Onsorting method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here I found that OnSorting is a method of GridView class.[image]

But in .aspx page we provide a method name for Onsorting as we provide value for any property. My question is Onsorting is not a property so why we give mathod name as we provide value for a property.[image]

Comment: Well, it has been a long time since I last wrote asp.net, but if memory serves, that's how you tell your asp control what method to activate on the server in response to a client event.

Answer (score 0):

GridViews are server side controls. The way you interact with their functionality is through methods in your code behind file.

In order to do this the GridView has a set of properties in the tag that when set will map to a method in your code behind.

So in your example, in the code behind for the page you have your Grid View on you should have a method like
`GridVeiw1_SortingMethod(GridViewSortEventArg e)
{
... Code goes here for sorting
}`